# Running Excel macro through Outlook: Run-time error '-2147417851(80010105)'

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have an Outlook project that save all attachments form selected e-mails to specific location. 
Then I have Excel workbook, that contain Macro, that checks stored files and do some stuff.
I want to call Excel Macro from Outlook Project, but I'm getting error:

***Run-time error '-2147417851(80010105)' Method 'Run' of object '_Application' failed***

Code, where I'm getting error is:

```
    Sub CheckRDSFiles()

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim files As TextStream
    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim exApp As Excel.Application
    Dim check_RDS As Workbook
    Dim readROW As String   

'Create complete folder to save files
    strFolderPath = SAVE_TO_FOLDER & Format(Now, "MMMM") & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyy-MM-DD") & "\"

'File that stores files to be processed
    Set files = fso.OpenTextFile(strFolderPath & "files.txt", ForReading, True, TristateUseDefault)

'Create excel application and open excel workbook with macro
    Set exApp = New Excel.Application
    Set check_RDS = exApp.Workbooks.Open(CHECK_RDS_PATH)
    exApp.Visible = True

'Reading file
    Do Until files.AtEndOfStream
'each line represent path to one file
        readROW = files.ReadLine
        Debug.Print readROW
'call macro from workbook "gatekeeper.xlsm" in module "Test" with name "test" and with parametres
        check_RDS.Application.Run "gatekeeper.xlsm!Test.test", readROW, strFolderPath
    Loop

End Sub
```

The error is on line:

```
check_RDS.Application.Run "gatekeeper.xlsm!Test.test", readROW, strFolderPath
```

The fun part is, that I'm able to run this without problem occasionaly, but I need to run it without problems everytime.

Also when I got this error, my Excel freeze and I have to shut it down using Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the line you're erroring on:

`check_RDS.Run "'gatekeeper.xlsm'!test", readROW, strFolderPath`

Comment: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method